# Как переписать данный код под PHP?

Tags: php, java

Имеется такой java код, как он будет выглядеть на PHP?
`this.lines.stream().filter(line -> line.getIndex() == index).findFirst().orElse(null);`

Answer (score 1):

Следует учитывать, что в PHP нет функционального стиля работы с коллекциями как это сделано в C# (Linq) или Java (StreamAPI). Поэтому аналогичные конструкции собирать придется из того, что есть в наличии и в случае их отсутствия, то писать обычные циклы и свои функции.

В данном случае для имитации filter можно использовать фильтрацию по массиву `array_filter` и анонимную функцию с замыканием, а для findFirst().orElse(null) получение первого элемента массива и тернарный оператор в случае если он вернется как false.

```
$arr = [
    (object) ["index" => 1],
    (object) ["index" => 2],
    (object) ["index" => 3]
];

function create_filter($index) {
    return function($v) use ($index) {
        return $v->index == $index;
    };
}

var_dump(reset(array_filter($arr, create_filter(3))) ?: null);
var_dump(reset(array_filter($arr, create_filter(1))) ?: null);
var_dump(reset(array_filter($arr, create_filter(4))) ?: null);
```

P.S. Он может ругаться `PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference`, поскольку reset меняет массив. Чтобы избежать ошибки, придется делать в две строки.

```
$result = array_filter($arr, create_filter(3));
var_dump(reset($result) ?: null);
```

P.P.S. В любом случае пытаться писать так же плохая идея, поскольку аналога нету или надо искать специальную библиотеку, которая будет учитывать все особенности таких конструкций изначально.

---

UPD: вообще это обычный поиск первого элемента, совпавшего по условию.

```
$arr = [
    (object) ["index" => 1],
    (object) ["index" => 2],
    (object) ["index" => 3]
];

function find($index, $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $line) {
        if ($line->index == $index) 
            return $line;
    }
    return null;
}

var_dump(find(2,$arr));
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: А что вообще это строка делает?

Comment: @user516883, какая из строк? Вообще подобный код сложнее для понимания. Если же из внешних библиотек, которые делают так же, можно посмотреть на примеры таких реализаций: https://github.com/hadasbro/php-stream-api

Comment: Та мне не нужна библиотека, у меня простенький код. Просто с java на пхп переписываю и увидел такую строку. Там всеголишь 2 класса по кусочку

Comment: Понятно, тогда лучше перепишите на обычный foreach, это просто поиск первого элемента у которого `if(line.getIndex() == index)` или если такого не нашлось, то вернуть null.

Comment: а вот так нормально? array_first($array, function ($lines) use ($this->lines) {
    return $lines >= $line;
});

Comment: @user516883 добавил пример обычной реализации без всяких излишеств в конец ответа. Если захотите усовершенствовать, думаю проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: или вот так? return (reset($this->lines->getIndex()) == $index) ?: null;

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Comment: Не за что, а так просто берите обычную итерацию через foreach, в ней хотя бы очень сложно ошибиться :) Я изначально просто подумал вопрос можно ли написать аналогично и хитро, а не просто перенести с минимум усилий и ошибок.